# How to assign same random number to more than one variable while creating new objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My javascript code looks something like this:

```
var balls = [];
var size = 10;

for(var i=0; i<size; i++){

    balls.push({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        radius: getRandomInt(20,50),
        mass : //here i want mass to have same value as that of radius.
    })
}
```

As I'm pushing newly created objects in my array of objects, I want the variables radius and mass to have same random number returned by `getRandomInt(20,50)`.

How do I achieve that? Writing `mass: radius` or `mass: this.radius` doesn't seem correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Assign the random number to a variable before the `push`, then `{ radius: randVar, mass: randVar }`…

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow @Swagnik Dutta, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store(assign) the random number to a temp variable then use it within the current scope.

```js
var balls = [];
var size = 10;

for(var i=0; i<size; i++){
    var temp = getRandomInt(20,50);
    console.log('this temp: ' + temp);
    balls.push({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        radius: temp,
        mass : temp
    })
}


function getRandomInt(min,max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is neat :) should have occurred to me.

Comment: @SwagnikDutta happy to help :D

Answer (score -1):

use a global variable and assign it to that when you run the function

```
var balls = [];
var size = 10;
var rndNum=0;

for(var i=0; i<size; i++){
getRandomInt(20,50);
    balls.push({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        radius: rndNum,
        mass : rndNum
    })
}

function getRandomInt(x,y){
rndNum=//do random math and assign to rndNum
}
```

Comment: Why this bending-over backwards with global variables?!

Comment: What if I want to get/use two random numbers?

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, it's that the use of global variables is insane.